# How to adjust image brightness of an image in Flutter and apply it directly to the file?

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing

I'm working on a Flutter application where I have a slider to adjust the brightness of an image. I want to apply the brightness adjustment the user can see on the screen, directly to the image file.

[image]

```
ColorFiltered(
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(
            ColorFilterGenerator.brightnessAdjustMatrix(
                value: _sliderBrightnessValue),
          ),
          child: Image.file(
            File(widget.imagePath),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
```

I don't know too much about image manipulation, but I found this matrice which works well with the slider :

```
class ColorFilterGenerator {
  static List<double> brightnessAdjustMatrix({required double value}) {
    value = (value <= 0) ? value * 255 : value * 100;
    return (value == 0) 
      ? [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
      : [1, 0, 0, 0, value, 0, 1, 0, 0, value, 0, 0, 1, 0, value, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0];
  }
}
```

The slider :

```
Slider(
              value: _sliderBrightnessValue,
              min: -0.5,
              max: 2,
              onChanged: (double value) {
                setState(() {
                  _sliderBrightnessValue = value;
                });
              },
            ),
```

And so I believe to transform the file itself, I need to use adjustColor() from the image package, but I don't know how to convert the slider value to get a similar result when calling adjustColor().
Currently I have this :

[image]

Top = the result of adjustColor()

Bottom = ColorFiltered

[Repo of the project](https://github.com/YofarDev/image_editor_test/blob/main/lib/image_editor_page.dart)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package if you want: https://pub.dev/packages/simple_fx
If you want to make it from scratch you can dig deep into this package source code and get inspired from the code.